# The JSX Code Refuse to Compile in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a problem  in my code .It refuse to compile  because of  all tags in jsx code problem, this problem named "Unreachable code detected (7027)"

---

Download the txt file  that contains the jsx code for more information ,link below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lEWqURdfmGQzYQLhCzfnVb79SNKqAzRX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning that hints you there's a logic problem in your code that leads to code that's absolutely unreachable. Either way, you'll have to show us the code causing the problem so we can help.

Comment: Check the guide on creating a [mcve]